# Get a list of locations 100 meters far from a geo point

Tags: android, geocoding, android-location

I have a list of places in my database, they all have a latitude / longitude.

In my app, I got the user location and I want to fetch all places which are 100 meters away from him.

To do it, I add 100 meters to his latitude, and longitude

I tried to do something like this:

```
 double radius = 100; // 100 meters

double limitLatitudeNorth = latitude + radius;
double limitLatitudeSouth = latitude - radius;

double limitLongitudeWest = longitude - radius;
double limitLongitudeEast = longitude + radius;

StringBuffer query = "latitude < '" + limitLatitudeNorth + "' AND latitude > '" + limitLatitudeSouth + "' AND longitude < '" + limitLongitudeWest + "' AND longitude > '" + limitLongitudeEast + "'";
```

But of course, laitude and longitude are not meters, so I don't know how make the sum.

What is the formula? I heard that it depends of the position in the globe. Let's say I'm in France.

A lot of apps do that (ie: LINE) I thought I will easily find a code for that, but I didn't: (

Any idea?

Comment: Get a list of locations 100 meters far from a geo point --> but  in which direction ?

Comment: with in 100 meters radius from a geo point

Comment: ok, What you are looking for is available using [Google Place API](https://developers.google.com/places/?hl=en) & [Google](https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr&ei=baHCUvrALs7_rAeg1oHoAg#q=android+%2B+Place+API+)

Comment: I have a list of users in my database, they all have a latitude / longitude. I need to check with them .

Comment: Well Study the place API , it should give you what you are looking for.

Comment: 'Location location = new Location();
location.setLatitude(latitude);
location.setLongitude(longitude);

Location locationFromDB = new Location();
locationFromDB.setLatitude(latitudeFromDB);
locationFromDB.setLongitude(longitudeFromDB);

float dist = location.distanceTo(locationFromDB);
if(dist<100f){
     //do here your magic
}'

Comment: I have a solution but need to do in a single SQLite query

Comment: hi do you post your answer here. @VishvaNathSingh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the distance between one point in your DB and the users current location. You can use Location.distanceBetween(). 
The Method returns an array of results with distance, bearing etc. The distance between the two locations is always in results[0].

I've written a small check. It calculates the distance and returns true, if the distance is smaller than your radius.

```
private boolean checkDistance(double currentLocLat, double currentLocLong, double placeLocLat, double placeLocLong) {
    float radius =  100F;
    float[] results = new float[3];
    Location.distanceBetween(currentLocLat, currentLocLong, placeLocLat, placeLocLong, results);
    return (results[0] <= radius);
}
```